# Insert into statements with variables in MariaDB transaction

Tags: variables, mariadb, set, sql-insert, declare

Hello everyone and thank you in advance:

I have a couple of tables with a very intricate relationship that require some input by the user. Ideally, I wanted to prompt the user for input as they go, but I didn't find a way to do it like you would in Oracle SQL with '&'. I tried triggers, I tried parameterized input statements with variables that would make things easy to read, but I am a noob, and MariaDB kept throwing errors at me, so I kept simplifying things down.

I figured having at least a transaction would be adequate to ensure data integrity and is more simple than a trigger that asks for inputs. Now, I run into problems when trying to insert a value created as a variable.

People.Entity_ID has Fiscal_Entities.Entity_ID as a foreign key, so first I create the row in Fiscal_Entities and then I try to store the highest PK auto-increment value as a variable and then pass it onto the next statement.

```
INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
SET @New_ID = (SELECT Max(Entity_ID) + 1 FROM Fiscal_Entities);
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (@New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);
```

but I get

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=5) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @New_ID = (SELECT Max(Entity_ID) + 1 FROM Fiscal_Entities);
INSERT INTO P...' at line 3
```

I have also tried declaring the variable before setting it, but it also fails. I have also tried running it as a transaction, but it didn't work either. And I have also tried declaring the variables without @.

Any ideas what is wrong with my syntax? I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a value into a variable:

```
SELECT Max(Entity_ID) + 1 into @New_ID FROM Fiscal_Entities;
```

Or you could consider using LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status) VALUES ('Physical', 3); 

SET @New_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); 

INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status) SELECT @New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3;
```

Comment: I like where you are going with LAST_INSERT_ID(). It looks like a very elegant solution, but I keep getting errors. I have tried playing with both suggestions.

The function didn't work because of a syntax error:
`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

Comment: Trying to SELECT the function didn't work:
`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

Comment: Trying to further isolate the function didn't work:
`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES ((SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()), 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

Comment: I also tried to substitute line 3 like this, but to no avail:

`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
SELECT Max(Entity_ID) into @New_ID FROM Fiscal_Entities;
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (@New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

It should actually be the same ID as in `Fiscal_Entities.Entity_ID`, so I have deleted the `+ 1` bit.

Comment: I have also tried just creating the variable with the function with and without the FROM statement, but it keeps throwing syntax errors at me:

`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() into @New_ID;
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (@New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

Comment: I have also tried creating the variable with SET and the function with and without the FROM statement, but it also throws a syntax error. I just don't see any syntax errors in any of my lines of code.

`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status)
VALUES ('Physical', 3);
SET @New_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status)
VALUES (@New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3);`

Comment: Try the following:
`INSERT INTO Fiscal_Entities (Nature, Client_Status) VALUES ('Physical', 3); SET @New_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID(); INSERT INTO People (Entity_ID, Sex, First_Given_Name, First_Family_Name, Pupil_Status, Teacher_Status) SELECT @New_ID, 'F', 'Toto', 'Tito', 3, 3;`

Comment: Finally! It works! Thank you, @Pat I! Do you want to edit your answer, so I can mark it as correct? So, because we want to include a variable in the values we enter, we use select instead of values. Is that right? 

It is so counter-intuitive. I don't understand why the syntax has to change so much. I do not agry with many design choices in the SQL language, but I am not in a position to change that ‍♂️